# How do I make the text from an input field appear on the screen after it is submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I would like to take whatever is entered into the input field and have it display on the screen after the user clicks submit. I know this seems super basic, but I am new to React. Thanks ahead of time!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class TextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { info: "", showName: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ info: evt.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.info}
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

      //text from input appears here
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: Do you mean like a popup? If so you could use a dialog box or create one yourself similar to this - https://dev.to/skptricks/create-simple-popup-example-in-react-application-5g7f

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you only want to display the text after the user clicks submit. In this case, you can use handleSubmit to set a special value in the state `submittedInfo` for example, and then display that value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class TextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { info: "", submittedInfo: "", showName: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ info: evt.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({submittedInfo: this.state.info})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.info}
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        //text from input appears here
        <div>{this.state.submittedInfo}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default TextInput;
```

Another approach could be to store in the state a boolean `isSubmitted`, signifying whether or not the user has submitted the form, and then displaying `this.state.info` if `isSubmitted` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

You already has state like,

```
this.state = { info: "", showName: false };
```

You can use `showName` state to show your text,

```
return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.info}
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        //text from input appears here
        {this.state.showName && <div>{this.state.info}</div>}

      </div>
    );
```

And your `handleSubmit` function should be,

```
handleSubmit(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({showName:true})
}
```